# passing parameters to function inside controller from child scope

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers (RegistrationController,ReportController) and one factory (StudentService). StudentService has a method calculate age which takes date as parameter.

It also has a list of students.

In RegistrationController there are two methods, calculateage which calls factory method and passes date which is taken from the form. second method adds the student to the list in factory. This works as it is supposed to.

In reportcontroller another list is populated from studentlist of factory.
This is displayed in a table. reportcontroller also has a method calculateage which calls the factory method for each student. But here i am not able to pass date to the factory method. So how do i send the date in reportcontroller method? The table is populated using ng-repeat on studentlist.

The factory is:

```
app.factory("StudentService",function(){
var factory={};

factory.calculateAge=function(dob){

    return age;
}

factory.studentList=[];

return factory;
})
```

RegistrationController:

```
app.controller("RegistrationController",function($scope,StudentService){

$scope.registrationForm.addStudent=function(){
    $scope.student={name:$scope.registrationForm.name,dateOfBirth:$scope.registrationForm.dateOfBirth};
    StudentService.studentList.push($scope.student);
};

$scope.calculateStudentAge=function(age){
    $scope.age=StudentService.calculateAge($scope.registrationForm.dateOfBirth);
};

});
```

ReportController:

```
app.controller("ReportController",function($scope,StudentService){
$scope.studentList=StudentService.studentList;  
$scope.calculateStudentAge=function(){
    return StudentService.calculateAge($scope.student.dateOfBirth);
};
});
```

The table of students: //edit- this is inside reportcontroller

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in studentList" ng-model="$parent.student">
    <td>{{student.name}}</td>
    <td>{{calculateStudentAge(student.dateOfBirth)}}</td>
</tr>
```

I tried passing $scope.student.dateOfBirth in calculateAge of reportController but it gives error as cannot read property dateOfBirth of undefined. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Just create your own add method in StudentService so that you have proper separations of concerns. Your controller should not be dealing with the calculating anything, it should be passed the information it needs to be displayed in the way it needs to display it. So put more logic into your StudentService

Comment: Alternatively you could just write a filter....

Comment: @CallumLinington yes, i did write a filter. But if i had to call it from controller how could i do it?

Comment: You don't call a filter from the controller!

Comment: @CallumLinington ofcourse not. I called it from <td>{{student.dateOfBirth|filter}}</td>> I am asking about calling factory method from controller. Sorry i didn't word the last comment properly

Comment: If I add a method inside studentservice, i would still need pass student object in it. Or can i access $scope variables inside service/factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in ReportController the 'calculateStudentAge' function is wrong. It should accept the parameter and pass it to service. as Follows,

```
$scope.calculateStudentAge=function(dob){
    return StudentService.calculateAge(dob);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a filter:

```
app.filter('age', ['StudentService', function(studentService) {
  return function(input) {
    return studentService.calculateAge(input);
  };
}])
```

NB: this is a very simplified version showing the basic usage, I would advise you do type checking and other verification to make sure you are working with the correct input.

So the row would look like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="student in studentList" ng-model="$parent.student">
    <td>{{student.name}}</td>
    <td>{{ student.dateOfBirth | age }}</td>
</tr>
```

You don't push and pull values from the view to the controller (when displaying them), you should think of it as a one way thing. You get values from your services and just simply pass them through the controller to the view.

The controller is just something for the view to bind onto and have a code representation of. Because it is javascript that is controlling the dropping in and out of views, it needs a JavaScript representation of a view, a.k.a the controller. The controller is there to bind you entire business/view logic written in JavaScript to your view.

To summarise, get your data looking exactly how you want in the service, then just pass this straight onto the controller for displaying in the view.

Comment: This works perfectly fine. I was also able to get it to work by setting ng-model of tr as "$parent.student=student". It works except i get an error in console as ng-model:noassign. Thanks